# Why is mdframed inserting a blank page?

Tags: page-breaking, mdframed

I'm using the awesome [mdframed](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) by Marco Daniel and I'm having some problems with pagination.  Sometimes it will insert a blank page, depending on the exact height of the content.  Here's the smallest MWE where I've been able to reproduce it:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\setstretch{1.5}
\lipsum[1]
\pagebreak
\begin{mdframed}[
  hidealllines=true,
  needspace=0pt,
]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[4]
\vspace{42.0pt}
% Tweak this number to the biggest value before "fill3 last line"
% moves to the next page.  At some point page 2 will end up blank.
% On my system, values 41.9 through 42.2 are bad.
% On writelatex.com, 51.9 through 52.2 are bad.
\lipsum[3]
fill1 \par
fill2 \par
fill3 last line \par
fill4 \par
fill5 \par
fill6 \par

\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

It's a bit sensitive, so it might be hard to reproduce.  Basically I tweak the `\vspace{42.0pt}` as large as possible before "fill3 last line" moves to the following page, and then a blank page gets inserted before the `mdframed` environment.  I've reproduced it at [writelatex.com here](https://www.writelatex.com/251831wkwwcs), with value `52.0pt`.

Any ideas why the blank page is showing up?

Comment: I can't test it at the moment, however I think writelatex.com i using an old version of mdframed.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I can reproduce the problem. I also get an overfull vbox 0.34436pt too high (which explains the blank page). Shouldn't in `\mdf@put@frame@i` the code in `\notbool{mdf@topline}` go in the other branch? I would have expected that space is added when a line is there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for the hint. Found the issue.

Comment: I fixed the issue. Please see my update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is only related to `framemethod=tikz`. I did the following stupid error. Sorry.

The default definition of the background is done by:

```
\tikzset{mdfbackground/.style={fill=\mdf@backgroundcolor,%
                               draw=\mdf@backgroundcolor,%
                              }%
        }
```

Although you draw a frame without any lines the bounding box calculation uses `draw=\mdf@backgroundcolor` which should be zero, but it isn't. So the correct setting is:

```
\tikzset{mdfbackground/.style={fill=\mdf@backgroundcolor,%
                               draw=none,%
                              }%
        }
```

With this knowledge you can fix your example with the following line:

```
\mdfsetup{apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={draw=none}}}}
```

The complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={draw=none}}}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\setstretch{1.5}
\lipsum[1]
\pagebreak
\begin{mdframed}[
  hidealllines=true,
%  backgroundcolor=yellow,%for testing
  needspace=0pt,
]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[4]
\vspace{42.0pt}
% Tweak this number to the biggest value before "fill3 last line"
% moves to the next page.  At some point page 2 will end up blank.
% On my system, values 41.9 through 42.2 are bad.
% On writelatex.com, 51.9 through 52.2 are bad.
\lipsum[3]
fill1 \par
fill2 \par
fill3 last line \par
fill4 \par
fill5 \par
fill6 \par

\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

---

It's really fascinating which influence such a small flaw has. The default path width were only 0.4pt -- unbelievable. However thanks for this great hint.

Comment: Great, thanks!  It was really rare, but it's great to have it fixed.

Comment: I have the same issue (without using framemethod=tikz), and this answer does not fix it.  My problem arises when I use a combination of the book class, fullpage, and lstlisting with mdframed.  MWE here: http://paste.ofcode.org/32GZVkABt7rkdrZgq4n6aeN